# DOM Excptn 8: Adding a Picture to a Div

Tags: javascript, dom, syntax-error

I'm creating this function that will add an image to a div that I'll later code to delete the information in said div. I keep getting the DOM Exception 8 error on this portion of the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
addDelete:function(imagename,idname) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", 'http://cpms.byu.edu/sites/all/themes/collage/src_submit/images/cross.png');
    img.setAttribute("id", imagename);
    document.getElementById(idname).appendChild("img");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(idname).appendChild("img");
                                            ^   ^
```

You are passing in the string `"img"`, not the variable `img`!

```
document.getElementById(idname).appendChild(img);
```